# Vue.js props copy and reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here's my problem: I have a v-for loop on a component.
The v-for loop is based on an array filtered by a search term entered in an input and returned by a computed.

The child component displays some data based on a copy of past props because I need to modify them.

The filtering works well but the content of the child components doesn't update correctly, being based on a copy of the props.

Here is a minimalist example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-engelbart-8iu4u?file=/src/App.vue

You can see in the console that the filtering is good, but the visual result is not (try filtering for example with the letters "ba").
How can I combine reactivity and props copy in a component ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Data shown correctly as they filtered.

Comment: No. Try filtering with "ba" for example, the name displayed is Einstein...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This caused by the `:key` isn't changing when you change the data since the `:key` value is based on the `v-for` index, not unique value that represent each user data.

Try adding `id` to the user object, and use it as the `:key` to make sure that each user data has its own unique `:key`

```js
users: [
    {
        id: 1,
        lastname: "Einstein",
        firstname: "Albert"
    },
    ...
]
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sun-optlr?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: It seems so obvious now that you're telling me ! Thanks a lot.