# How to insert a dom element in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have vue JS file and inside it, I am displaying images using 'v-for'. Check below code

```html
    <div id="peopleimages">
          <img
            :src="item.thumbnailLink"
            v-bind:id="'profile'+item.id"
            v-masonry-tile
            class="item"
            v-for="(item, index) in images"
            :key="index"
          />
    </div>
```

The above code will display list of images that are fetched from server.

Now, I wanted to explicitly insert an image as the first image. After which, the list of images should be populated.

I tried using Java script, but it turns out, I cannot insert  tag inside vue js file.

How do i explicitly insert an image at the start?

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to set a default image followed by images fetched from server?

Comment: Absolutely. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to just insert another image into the beginning of `images` array:

```js
const newImage = {
    thumbnailLink: "path-to-new-image",
    id: "unique-id"
}

this.images.unshift(newImage);
```

Keep in mind if you are using index as the `:key`, it can cause some [unwanted behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61804316/12397250) when you are changing the element order.

Another way is to create a data that's not part of the images array and show it conditionally on the template

```html
<div id="peopleimages">
      <img
        v-if="firstImage"
        :src="firstImage"
        class="item" />
      <img
        :src="item.thumbnailLink"
        v-bind:id="'profile'+item.id"
        v-masonry-tile
        class="item"
        v-for="(item, index) in images"
        :key="index"
      />
</div>
```

and on the script

```js
data() {
    return {
        firstImage: ""   
    }
},

methods: {
    setFirstImage() {
        this.firstImage = "path-to-first-image"
    }
}
```